# Creating inventory rules

Tags: catalog, inventory, rules

I have configurable products in my product catalog that i would like to assign a rule to the quanity in stock.

for example

if i sell sku 2005, inventory needs to remove 1 from sku abc and 1 from sku abcd
if i sell sku 2006 inventory needs to remove 1 from sku abc and 2 from sku abcd etc etc

if i sell sku 2007 inventory needs to remove 1 from sku ade 2 from sku adef and 3 from sku from adefg

Can anyone shed some light on programming this?

Comment: Can you fix this with bundle products?

So SKU 2005 is :
1 x ABC
1 x ABCD

SKU 2006
1 x ABC 
2 x ABCD

SKU 2007
2 x ADEF
3 x ADEFG